# Selected row in listbox copied to another listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox within a userform with a few rows of filtered data.  I would like to be able to select one of the rows and have it appear in another listbox (just the values within that selected row, none of the others)

My current code is just:

```
Private Sub SelectHousingList_Click()
HousingList.Text = SelectHousingList.Selected(Row)
End Sub
```

With 'HousingList' being the listbox that I'd like the values to move to.

And 'SelectHousingList' being the rows of filtered data.

Previously in this code I've used code similar to this to select from a list of values (but not with a whole row of values).

```
Private Sub MaterialList_Click()
SelectedMaterialText.Value = MaterialList.Text
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("D4").Value = SelectedMaterialText.Value
End Sub
```

The second line of code allows for the selected item in the list to be copied to a textbox.

If you need more of my code I can supply you with it.

This may be a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere or figure out code that allows it to happen.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a multicolumn list and you need all the columns values of the selected row? Or only the list value of its ListIndex?

Comment: I would like for all of the columns values to be copied to the next yes.

Comment: How many columns are there in your list box? I posted a code able to retrieve all columns value of the selected row. Do you have another listbox and you need to add at the end the values of the first one selected row?

Comment: My code copies all the columns values of the selected row into the second listbox, for all column existing range...

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried using your code as well but was given an output of every value in the first column, not the selected row.

Comment: Please refresh the page and try testing it again. It is able to copy all the columns how many they are. Tested on my computer.  I Initially did not understand how to columns value of the selected row to be used. Then I added a last part, able to do that for  all existing columns. The obtained array can also be used for whatever other need, if any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, this should do what you need for a single column:

```
Private Sub SelectHousingList_Click()
   HousingList.AddItem SelectHousingList.Value
End Sub
```

If there are 2 columns, then this:

```
Private Sub SelectHousingList_Click()
   HousingList.AddItem SelectHousingList.List(SelectHousingList.ListIndex)
   HousingList.List(HousingList.ListCount - 1, 1) = SelectHousingList.List(SelectHousingList.ListIndex, 1)
End Sub
```

You'll need to add additional lines for every column beyond 2, changing the index for each one.

Comment: This worked more than what I had before, though it only adds the first part of the row, not the entire row itself.  

I'll see if I can get it to work though.  

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This edited version is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JoshL Glad to help.  If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: It doesn't show my upvotes until I have 10 rep (at 9 right now!) but I did check that mark now.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This code retrieves in an array (or string) all the columns values on the selected row. It fills the second listbox with as many columns first one has:

```
Private Sub SelectHousingList_Click()
  Dim arrRow() As Variant, i As Long
  ReDim arrRow(Me.SelectHousingList.ColumnCount)
  For i = 0 To SelectHousingList.ColumnCount
    arrRow(i) = Me.SelectHousingList.List(i, Me.SelectHousingList.ListIndex)
  Next i
  Debug.Print Join(arrRow, ", ")
   With Me.HousingList
     .ColumnCount = Me.SelectHousingList.ColumnCount
     .AddItem arrRow(0)
      For i = 1 To UBound(arrRow)
          .List(.ListCount - 1, i) = arrRow(i)
      Next i
  End With
End Sub
```